# JPanel drawing chart in a loop. need help for swing gui

Tags: java, swing, charts, graphics

I am trying to draw charts in a tab of a `JTabbedPane`. Each tab contains a `JPanel` but my code drawing charts to tab which is opened in front of me, not to constant tab.

```
public class Grafik extends JPanel {
public Grafik(){
    try {
         //this block for opening ready chart images to using in panel.
        Arayuz.imageGrafikSicaklik = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File("Sıcaklık.png")));
        Arayuz.imageGrafikBasinc = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File("Basınç.png")));
        Arayuz.imageGrafikHiz = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File("Hız.png")));
        Arayuz.imageGrafikYukseklik = ImageIO.read(new FileImageInputStream(new File("Yükseklik.png")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawImage(Arayuz.imageGrafikSicaklik, 36, 16, Arayuz.imageGrafikSicaklik.getWidth(), Arayuz.imageGrafikSicaklik.getHeight(), this);
    g.drawImage(Arayuz.imageGrafikBasinc, 736, 16, Arayuz.imageGrafikBasinc.getWidth(), Arayuz.imageGrafikBasinc.getHeight(), this);
    g.drawImage(Arayuz.imageGrafikHiz, 36, 398, Arayuz.imageGrafikHiz.getWidth(), Arayuz.imageGrafikHiz.getHeight(), this);
    g.drawImage(Arayuz.imageGrafikYukseklik, 740, 398, Arayuz.imageGrafikYukseklik.getWidth(), (Arayuz.imageGrafikYukseklik.getHeight()*1009)/1000, this);
    //Arayuz.ggg = Arayuz.grafikPaneli.getGraphics();
}

public void grafikCizimSıcaklık(JPanel grafikpaneli, int startX, double instantHeat){
    Graphics cizici = grafikpaneli.getGraphics();
    cizici.drawLine(startX,(int) (280 - (instantHeat / 3) * 20), startX + 3, (int) (280 - (instantHeat / 3) * 20));
}
```

First of all while I am watching chart's Tab, everything is correct for now.

[image: good chart]

When I switch to another tab, charts will be deleted and starting to draw in that tab and that is my problem.

[image: bad chart]

The first chart deleted and charts are continue in another tab which is i am watching.

I hope that I can explain my problem correctly. Thanks for everything from now.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the images, i.e. `Sıcaklık.png` and the others? If you [edit] your question and post a [mcve], I can try to reproduce your problem and then, hopefully, find a solution for it. By the way, you should override method `paintComponent()` and not method `paint()`.

Comment: The code posted apparently draws 3 images on one JPanel.

Comment: I have 4 images on one JPanel but does it matter ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JLabel and put the image, otherwise you should put the background image by overwriting the paintcomponent().

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

You class should extends JPanel and you need an Image:

```
private BufferedImage image;


    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("HERE ADD YOUR IMG PATH));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("errorImgPath" + ex.toString());
    }
```

Comment: I did this but it could not solve my problem. when I switch the Tab, images are constant but charts rubbing off.

Comment: what you dont want is to keep the chart on every tab?

Comment: I want to keep chart only "Grafikler" tab. When I switch the tab, please chart do not rub off and chart do not going to draw another Tab.